# Merge two sorted linked lists java inplace

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Could some one give code for merging 2 sorted LLs in place?

recursion & also iterative please

Thanks
Dinesh

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There are two basic algorithms. 1: create an empty list and merge the two lists into the empty list. 2: merge the second list into the first list. Both of these are iterative algorithms. Recursion would just replace iteration at the potential cost of 1 stack frame per element merged, unless the compiler optimized the recursion back into iteration.

Comment: Could you pay me $100 per hour for my time, please? The whole idea of these assignments is to learn how to solve problems, not to copy somebody else's work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MergeLinkedLists {

public static Node merge(Node head1, Node head2) {
    Node mergedList = null;
    if(head1 == null) {
        return head2;
    }
    if(head2 == null) {
        return head1;
    }
    if(head1.data < head2.data) {
        //point to smaller element
        mergedList = head1;         
        mergedList.next = merge(head1.next, head2);
    } else { //head1 is large, so pass h
        //point to smaller element
        mergedList = head2;
        //head2 is already consider
        //now process next node of head2
        mergedList.next = merge(head1, head2.next);
    }
    return mergedList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick recursive solution in python. The implementation logic should be the same in Java

```
def mergeLists(head1, head2):
  if not head1:
      return head2

  if not head2:
      return head1

  if head1.data <= head2.data:
      res = head1
      res.next = mergeLists(head1.next, head2)
  else:
      res = head2
      res.next = mergeLists(head1, head2.next)

  return res
```